# Is knowing the MTK processor version sufficient to get the right twrp image on Android device?

Tags: root-access, twrp, mediatek

If I download a twrp image depending on the MTK processor version and not the device name/ manufacturer, will I be wrong ? and will it be 100% working?

Note: the device is not rooted, I am actually trying to root it this way(No other way is working), so let's focus on the question.

Comment: You need to modify the fstab of the TWRP version along with many other files of the TWRP version you are willing to use in order to flash the recovery on your device. What is the MTK version of your Android device?

Comment: my mtk version is : "mt6735"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work that way.

TWRP depends heavily on the `fstab` of the device model in question, which describes the partition layout of the storage. This is not related to the SoC (processor), and almost never the same between different models.

Comment: so if i get the scatter file , i can use iti think

Comment: TWRP is *built* with fstab, so if I understand correctly, supplying a scatter *externally* won't help. Scatters are only there to help you flash it in, not actually use it. [**Note to others:** I have no hands-on knowledge about MTK phones; feel free to correct me if you're knowledgeable]

Comment: No , i think you are right , scatter files descripes the structure of memory

Answer (score 0):

You would probably get your device bricked. When you are making a TWRP (porting or building from source) it will need your kernel, so no, TWRP from other device won't on your device.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the chipset is one step. You need to also know the Android version of your device. Then download a working TWRP for the MT6735 on the same Android version. You can  then port it to your device as usual. 
Just flashing the downloaded recovery may not work/boot up unless you port the kernel files, storage files, base etc using that from your own stock recovery. If you do this, you will get a working TWRP for your device.

Comment: so you think if i know the mtk version +android version , the corresponding TWRP image is 100% safe , i don't really agree , i guess some phones of the same mtk family would need diffrent TWRP images becausethey are not really that simular